# format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double *’, but argument 2 has type ‘polyTerm **

Tags: c++, c

This is the header file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef POLYNOMIAL_H
#define POLYNOMIAL_H

//////////////////////////////////////
// define structure for polynomial's
//////////////////////////////////////
typedef struct {
  double coeff; //varible for coeff type
} polyTerm;     //poly expoent will be array index value

/////////////////////////////////
// Define a polynomial
/////////////////////////////////
typedef struct {
  int used;           // slots used so far
  int capacity;       // total available slots
  polyTerm *data;     // array of type polyTerm we're storing
} polynomial;


polynomial* createPoly (int capacity);

#endif
```

This is the main file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "polynomial.h"

int select = -1;
int maxExpo;//max expoent of polynoimal also max array length of which index is
        //expoent and is passed to the funtion as below.

int main()
{
  while (select != 0)
    {
      //user menu to select operations
      printf("\t(0) Exit program\n");
      printf("\t(1) Create new polynomial\n");
      printf("\t(2) Delete polynomial\n");
      printf("\t(3) Add polynomials\n");
      printf("\t(4) Subtract polynomials\n");
      printf("\t(5) Multiply polynomials\n");
      printf("\t(6) Divide polynomials\n");
      printf("\t(7) Normalise polynomials\n");
      printf("\t(8) Return order of polynomial\n");
      printf("\t(9) Print polynomial\n");
      printf("\nPlease select any operation 0-9:");
      scanf("%d",&select);

      switch (select)
    {
    case 0: //Exit program
      break;
    case 1:  //create a poly
        printf("\tPlease enter highest polynomial degree value of poly 1: ");
        scanf("%i",&maxExpo); 
        polynomial *p1 = createPoly(maxExpo); //polynomial array number 1
            for (int i=0; i<=maxExpo; i++)
      {
        printf("\tPlease enter coeff of x^%i :",i);
        scanf("%lf",&(p1[i].data));
      }
        //polynomial *p2 = createPoly(n); //polynomial array number 2
        // polynomial *result = createPoly(size of max degree of both poly's);
        //polynomial array number 3 which is the math function result array.


      break;
    case 2: //Delete poly

      break;
    case 3: //Add poly

      break;
    case 4: //Subtract poly

      break;
    case 5: //Mulyiply poly

      break;
        case 6: //divide poly

      break;
    case 7: //Normalise poly

      break;
    case 8: //Return order of poly

      break;
    case 9: //Print poly

      break;
    default : //invalid selection
      printf("\tInvalid selection please select one of the above operations 0-9\n\n");
    }
    }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is the function to create a polynomial:

```
 polynomial* createPoly (int capacity){

  polynomial *inPoly;
  inPoly = (polynomial *) malloc(sizeof(polynomial));

  if (inPoly != NULL)
    {
    //int number = capacity * sizeof(polynomial);
      inPoly->data = (polyTerm *) calloc(capacity , sizeof(polyTerm));

      if (inPoly->data != NULL)  {
    // do something (allocation was successful)
    //inPoly->data = NULL;
    inPoly->capacity = capacity;
    inPoly->used = 0;
      } else {
    // allocation failed, clean up
    free(inPoly);
    inPoly = NULL;
    }

    }


    return inPoly;
}
```

I get the following error when i compile

```
gcc -Wall -ggdb -std=c11 -o main polynomialMain.c -lm
polynomialMain.c: In function ‘main’:
polynomialMain.c:45:12: warning: format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double *’, but argument 2 has type ‘polyTerm ** {aka struct <anonymous> **}’ [-Wformat=]
      scanf("%lf",&(p1[i].data));
            ^
/tmp/ccHfHTgF.o: In function `main':
/polynomialMain.c:41: undefined reference to `createPoly'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'polynomialMain' failed
make: *** [polynomialMain] Error 1
```

i am only new to c code and must of the above i don't understand i am having a tough time with it. any help will be much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: This is among the least [mcve] I know.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Error says it all.  `%lf` expects a `double *` but you pass in a `polyTerm **`

Comment: hi i accept your answer but how do i sort it out i dont understand and this is a falling on my part not yours thanks :)

Comment: Check out dbush's answer.  That solution may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are different languages.  In C++, you don't need the `typedef` before the `struct`.  In C++, you can overload `operator<<` to print the polynomial, and not worry about format specifiers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
  polynomial *p1 = createPoly(maxExpo);
  for (int i=0; i<=maxExpo; i++)
  {
    printf("\tPlease enter coeff of x^%i :",i);
    scanf("%lf",&(p1[i].data));
  }
```

The field `p1[i].data` is a `polyTerm *` (and it's address is of type `polyTerm **`).  The `scanf` is expecting the address of a `double`.

The `createPoly` function is only returning a pointer to a single `polynomial`, so `p1[i]` doesn't make sense as that implies an array of `polynomial`.  Since the `data` member points to an array of `polyTerm`, and each of those contains a field of type `double`, that's probably what you want to write to:

```
scanf("%lf",&(p1->data[i].coeff));
```